# libz dylib with static link not support iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, php-ziparchive, libz

Details in my project:

1. Using swift 1
2. Need support iOS 7
3. Using [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)
4. Not use cocoapods or something else

On my project, i need unzip something. So i'm using ZipArchive, this is dynamic linking. Works on project when i'm not archive(means xcode archive) and put on testflight.

But when upload to testflight, iOS 7 not support dynamic linking, so it's failed.

I'm try to create a new **Static Library** target, but dylib is **still need dynamic linking**. It's conflict...

How to deal with this?

First solution on my mind is: Require zlib's source code, but this is very complex....

*Maybe find some other way to unzip archive with swift will be more simple*?

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolved my problem currently.

Just include all ZipArchive's file to Build Phases (*.c/*.m -> Compile Sources, *.h -> Headers -> Project)

Include header in bridge file, They will slow down compile but works.

Not sure any possible issue for future.